# Twisted and enabling command line history

Tags: python, twisted

In a previous question of mine I got this answer:

> Subclass `twisted.conch.recvline.HistoricRecvLine` instead of `twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver`. `keystrokeReceived` is one of the several additional protocol callbacks available when you are using a terminal instead of a TCP connection. – Jean-Paul Calderone

But what if what to have both terminal and TCP Connection? When I subclass `HistoricRecvLine` I lose the functionality of the TCP connection? So let's start it from the beginning. My `.py` file is:

```
class WebCheckerCommandProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("checker console. Type 'help' for help.")

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        ...

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        # stop the reactor, only because this is meant to be run in Stdio.
        reactor.stop()

    def do_listservers(self):
        "Cmd to Query all available Servers - Takes no arguments"
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(ip+":"+port)
        conn.request(.....)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        print response.status, response.reason
        data = response.read()
    def do_sessions(self):
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(ip+":"+port)
        conn.request(.....)

    def do_logUser(self, name):
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(ip+":"+port)
        conn.request(.....)


class SimpleServer(LineReceiver):

    def connectionMade(self):
        print 'Connection from: ', self.transport.client

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print self.transport.client, 'Disconnected'

    def dataReceived(self, line):
        """Here the XML Parser"""
        print line

if __name__ == "__main__":
    factory = Factory()
    factory.protocol = SimpleServer

    stdio.StandardIO(SimpleServer())
    reactor.listenTCP(1234, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

How to enable command history?  How do I combine all that you suggest me to achieve what I want?

Obviously I'm missing something!

Comment: "When i subclass HistoricRecvLine i loose the functionality of the TCP connection?"  Not at all.  Why do you say this?

Comment: Because i used the sedLine() method which is now unavailable.
The runWithProtocol class is still required if i subclass HistoricRecvLine? And should i pass to it, the class WebCheckerCommandProtocol(HistoricRecvLine)?
Antonis Kaklis

Comment: Well in latest attempt i got:
 File "/twisted/conch/stdio.py", line 74, in runWithProtocol
    stdio.StandardIO(p)
  File "/twisted/internet/_posixstdio.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.protocol.makeConnection(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 349, in makeConnection
    self.connectionMade()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/conch/insults/insults.py", line 414, in connectionMade
    self.terminalProtocol = self.protocolFactory(*self.protocolArgs, **self.protocolKwArgs)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)